# Is there an equivalent of method WorkingMemory.assertObject in Drools 6.0.1?

Tags: java, drools

I'm trying to upgrade my app from Drools 2.0 to 6.0.1. In my code, I have something like that :

```
        workingMem.assertObject(fact);
```

The thing is that there is no longer assertObject method in WorkingMemory class.

According to [this website](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/DROOLS/Working+Memory#WorkingMemory-assertObject), this method do that :

> "Objects are asserted into the WorkingMemory, which allows the rule-engine to be aware of its existence, and a fact handle is returned as a reference. Once asserted, the fact may be used to satisfy some portion of any rule's activation condition."

I can't find any equivalent in Drools 6.0.1. Is there any way to get around this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find the method - renamed to insert due to the obvious clash with assert - in interface `org.kie.api.runtime.rule.EntryPoint`:

```
FactHandle insert(Object object)

Inserts a new fact into this entry point

Parameters:
    object - the fact to be inserted 
Returns:
    the fact handle created for the given fact
```

EntryPoint is extended into interface `KieSession`, which is the pivot object for fact storage and engine activation.